# K-Cups - Powdered Milk

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I have been using K Cups (small "cups" or "pods" made for a Keurig beverage machine) for a while now and I just realized that some of them contain milk powder. Is it okay to drink? Is it kosher at all?

Comment: Some are, some aren't. Rules are not applicable to K-Cups in general as different companies make different specific products differently.

Comment: Supplementing @Danno's comment, you should assume they are not OK unless they have some reliable kosher certification or you ask a rabbi or mashgiach who is familiar with the specific product.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38172/can-i-use-a-keurig-coffee-machine-if-someone-else-has-used-a-non-kosher-pod

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya S! Thanks for sharing the question.

Comment: The K cups that we have in our home have the OU (no D so they are pareve) on the top of each individual cup of coffee. Other brands have other hecsheirim. For example Bright Tea packets have KLBD (Kosher London Bais Din) and are pareve

Answer (score 2):

OU have a [page dealing with Keurig Green Mountain products](https://oukosher.org/letter-of-kosher-certification/)   relating to the kashrus of K-cups and other prodcuts. There are dairy products. You can check any individual Keurig product there.

The certificates state that the relevant OU symbol is required.

Related to this, the [news item from “Kosher Today”](http://www.koshertoday.com/breaking-news-woes-kosher-coffee-drinkers-k-cups-omit-ou-symbol/)  says

> According to Rabbi Moshe Elefant, COO of the Orthodox Union (OU)
>   Kashrus Division, certified kosher K-Cups used in the machines no
>   longer have the OU symbol on the individual cups although they remain
>   on the boxes that they come in. Thus, a kosher consumer who randomly
>   finds a K-Cup without a box may inadvertently be using a non-certified
>   K-Cup … etc